# find which of the columns in postgis table are of type geometry and which are attributes

Tags: python, postgresql, geometry, postgis

I need to find all the columns which holds geometry values in a postgres table, I am trying to make it work like this. But I am not really sure that it will work all the time.

```
list_geometry_columns = pd.read_sql_query(f"""select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = '{schema_name}' and table_name = '{tbl_name}' and data_type='USER-DEFINED'""",con=engine)['column_name'].tolist()
list_attrib_columns = pd.read_sql_query(f"""select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = '{schema_name}' and table_name = '{tbl_name}' and data_type!='USER-DEFINED'""",con=engine)['column_name'].tolist()
```

In my current implementation 'USER-DEFINED' may be present for other columns as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the `geometry_column` view (or `geography_column`) to get the geometries

```sql
SELECT *
FROM geometry_columns
WHERE f_table_schema = 'myschema'
AND f_table_name = 'myTable';
```

Alternatively, you can get the list of every column type/format type and filter for geometry:

```sql
SELECT
    pg_attribute.attname AS column_name,
    pg_type.typname AS data_type,
    pg_catalog.format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) AS format_type
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_attribute
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type
    ON pg_attribute.atttypid = pg_type.oid
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_class ON pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
WHERE
    pg_attribute.attnum > 0
    AND NOT pg_attribute.attisdropped
    --AND pg_type.typname = 'geometry'
    AND pg_namespace.nspname = 'public'
    AND pg_class.relname = 'my_table'
ORDER BY
    attnum ASC;
```

Comment: thanks @JGH, but My view shows to be empty, So I am not getting any of the column name.

Comment: @bhavesh that's strange... see my edit with another way to get the information relying on pg_catalog